# How to add an and condition to the query only when the column is not null?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the below query which is giving correct output when the t2.date is not null

```
select t1.name,t1.work,t2.type from t1,t2 where t.name=t2.name and t1.postdate < t2.date
```

But when the t2.date is null the query is not fetching any rows. So I want to add the `t1.postdate < t2.date`condition only when the t2.date is not null.

When the t2.date is null I don't want to add it to the query(I want the output as the above query gives without and condition)

```
select t1.name,t1.work,t2.type from t1,t2 where t.name=t2.name
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and (t1.postdate < t2.date OR t2.date is NULL)?

Comment: So what if I find both a record with a matching date and one with date null for a name? Do you want to join both? Or only the one with the date? With SQL questions it is always advisable to show some sample data and expected result. You are using an out-dated join syntax by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I agree to @jarlh, you can use this maybe;

```
select t1.name,t1.work,t2.type from t1,t2 where t.name=t2.name and (t2.date is null or t1.postdate < t2.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not uise NVL to make it clearer and shorter?

```
select t1.name
      ,t1.work
      ,t2.type 
  from t1 
      ,t2 
 where t.name = t2.name 
   and t1.postdate < nvl(t2.date, t1.postdate + 1);
```